# Resetting network adapter?

Tags: networking, reset, adapter

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. I get a strong wireless signal throughout my house, and the wireless symbol in the upper-right-hand corner shows that it's connected. The problem is, occasionally I am unable to access the internet (still having a strong symbol). This happened with Windows 7, too, but running the network troubleshooter fixed it each time. It claimed to be "resetting the network adapter".

So, what I need to know is: How do I replicate that process on Ubuntu?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely that the problem is actually with your wireless access point or router, and that the fix you've described on Windows is just a workaround for the problem.

If that is the case, then you can reproduce the important part of the fix (disconnecting from, and reconnecting to, the wireless network) in Ubuntu by clicking on the networking icon in the notification area, disconnecting, and reconnecting.

Comment: Yep, it's definitely a problem with the modem/router/vonage-thing complex. I can get the internet to work by turning them all off and back on again, but unfortunately, disconnecting and reconnecting to the network from my laptop doesn't work.